# javafx8 resize grows never shrinks

Tags: resize, javafx-8

I have the following sample code fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
<?import org.cornova.javafx.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" minHeight="0" minWidth="0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.cornova.javafx.PanController">
  <items>
      <HBox prefHeight="246.0" prefWidth="603.0">
         <children>
            <VBox HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <StackPane fx:id="stackPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="165.0" prefWidth="570.0">
                     <children>
                        <ResizableCanvas fx:id="spectrum" height="195.0" width="573.0" StackPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT" />
                     </children>
                  </StackPane>
                  <ResizableCanvas fx:id="freqScale" height="10.0" width="570.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <ResizableCanvas fx:id="dbmScale" height="195.0" width="30.0" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
  </items>
</SplitPane>
```

I couple that with the following controller

```
/*
 * Here comes the text of your license
 * Each line should be prefixed with  * 
 */
package org.cornova.javafx;

/**
 * Sample Skeleton for 'PanView.fxml' Controller Class
 */

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import org.cornova.javafx.ResizableCanvas;

public class PanController {

    @FXML // ResourceBundle that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML // URL location of the FXML file that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private URL location;

    @FXML // fx:id="stackPane"
    private StackPane stackPane; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="spectrum"
    private ResizableCanvas spectrum; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="freqScale"
    private ResizableCanvas freqScale; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="dbmScale"
    private ResizableCanvas dbmScale; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
    void initialize() {
        assert stackPane != null : "fx:id=\"stackPane\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'PanView.fxml'.";
        assert spectrum != null : "fx:id=\"spectrum\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'PanView.fxml'.";
        assert freqScale != null : "fx:id=\"freqScale\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'PanView.fxml'.";
        assert dbmScale != null : "fx:id=\"dbmScale\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'PanView.fxml'.";

        spectrum.widthProperty().bind(stackPane.widthProperty());
        spectrum.heightProperty().bind(stackPane.heightProperty());
        freqScale.widthProperty().bind(stackPane.widthProperty());
        dbmScale.heightProperty().bind(stackPane.heightProperty());
        spectrum.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("spectrum width changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
        });
        spectrum.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("spectrum height changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
        });
        freqScale.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("Freq scale width changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
        });
        dbmScale.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("dbm scale height changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
        });

        stackPane.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("stackpane width changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
        });
        stackPane.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("stackpane height changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
        });
    }
}
```

Given these two, as I recall, my sample app

```
package org.cornova.portablesdr;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author walt
 */
public class PanadapterView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try {
            URL url = getClass().getResource("/PanView.fxml");
            SplitPane root = (SplitPane)FXMLLoader.load(url);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(PanadapterView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

worked pretty much as I expected except the enlargement of the window only went so far and I could not shrink it, at all.  I added a change listener to the vbox and hbox and they both perform properly with respect to growth and shrinkage.

The two scales I want fixed on one axis, the HBox contains a VBox and a resizableCanvas as described in FXControl. It has a fixed width and its height is paired to the height of the stackpane, a child VBox and parent of another ResizableCanvas.

In the current fxml file I believe  the stackpane appear to be fine in width, I can grow and shrink it just fine but the height never exceeds 200, which I was forced to use for prefHeight. It can, however, override prefWidth just fine.

At this point I kind of find myself just guessing at what to change next. I really have been trying to research this issue..so far with no luck, clearly.
Here is the final fxml file.

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0" minWidth="0" orientation="VERTICAL" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.cornova.javafx.PanController">
  <items>
      <HBox fx:id="hbox" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0">
         <children>
            <VBox fx:id="vbox" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="170.0" prefWidth="570.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <StackPane fx:id="stackPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="570.0">
                     <children>
                        <ResizableCanvas fx:id="spectrum" />
                     </children>
                  </StackPane>
                  <ResizableCanvas fx:id="freqScale" height="30.0" width="570.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <ResizableCanvas fx:id="dbmScale" height="200.0" width="30.0" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
  </items>
</SplitPane>
```

I hope this all makes sense. Clearly there is something I am missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the Stackpane had (in SceneBuilder) a Vgrow setting of inherit, which I can't find explained anywhere and it doesn't appear to be a value in the Priority enum.

If someone would illuminate the purpose of inherit I, and I am sure others, would appreciate it.

Comment: "Inherit" is described in the [JavaFX CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeinherit)

Comment: setManaged(false) did it for me. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49829217/1390116